# Offset Anniversary Date

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have an anniversary date in C2, and other anniversary date from E3 to E6.

I want that if Anniversary date < Today then

the C2 value is the next anniversary Date.

[image: Exemple]

With this exemple, if today we are the 02/11/2018, the C2 value will be 11/02/2019 (E3). And then, after the 11/02/2019, it will be 30/03/2020 (E4)...

I want to do it with Excel formulas , I tried something like this :

```
=SI(C2<=TODAY();OFFSET(E3;1;0);C2)
```

But it doesn't work...

Maybe in VBA if no one have formulas ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C2 try,

```
=aggregate(15, 7, (e3:index(e:e, match(1e99, e:e)))/(e3:index(e:e, match(1e99, e:e))>today()), 1)
'with semi-colon list separator
=aggregate(15; 7; (e3:index(e:e; match(1e99; e:e)))/(e3:index(e:e; match(1e99; e:e))>today()); 1)
'aggreagte was introduced with xl2010, for xl2003-xl2007 use,
=MIN(INDEX(E3:INDEX(E:E, MATCH(1E+99, E:E))+(E3:INDEX(E:E, MATCH(1E+99, E:E))<=TODAY())*1E+99, , ))
'in FR-FR
=AGREGAT(15; 7; (e3:index(e:e; EQUIV(1e99; e:e)))/(e3:index(e:e; EQUIV(1e99; e:e))>AUJOURDHUI()); 1)
```

Remember to format C2 as a date or you might end up with a number like 43402.

Comment: Same thing... maybe it's a translation problem ? I hate my french Excel... I know that Today is AUJOURDHUI, MATCH is EQUIV...

Comment: Try [AGREGAT](https://support.office.com/fr-fr/article/agregat-agregat-fonction-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df) for [AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/agregat-agregat-fonction-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df).

Comment: I have a date with this : =AGREGAT(15; 7; (E3:INDEX(E:E; EQUIV(1E+99; E:E)))/(E3:INDEX(E:E; EQUIV(1E+99; E:E))>AUJOURDHUI()); 1). But it's hard to know if it's working because I can't test it with TODAY fonction. I need to wait tomorrow see if it's changing ?